# jquery merge all the same request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote a ajax api in server side to get a random column from 
a table in database used Express and nodejs, and request this interface in a loop for 10 times in the client side.However, every loop I get 10 same response.

After I test, I found that even I called the api with jquery(v1.11.1) for 10 times, I just get one request in server side; Then I add a different param in the option [data] of [$.ajax()], and I get ten request in server side and 10 different response in cilent side;
I thought this is  a default setting of [$.ajax], so I try to find this in the document of jquery,and, I didn't find it.(google also find nothing) ;

I do solve this problem with a different param for every requests, but I don't think this is the best solution. So, my question is:

Is there any setting to send a unique request for every requests even these requests are all the same when using jquery(v1.11.1)?

ps: forgive my poor english level,I can't express myself better...

```
for( var i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
    $.ajax( {
        type: "get",
        url: "/getNickname",
        data: {
            //index: i //my solution
        },
        beforeSend: function ( request ) {

        },
        success: function ( res ) {
            console.log( "test response is ", JSON.stringify( res ) );
        },
        error: function ( err ) {
            reject( err );
        }
    } );
}
//below is the function to get a random column from table
function getNicknameFromDB() {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        pg_pool.query( "select nickname from robot_nick_datas offset random() * (select count(*) from robot_nick_datas) limit 1;", (err, result)=> {
            if( err ){
                console.error( "query error: ", err );
                reject(err);
            }
            let nickname = Array.from(result.rows)[0];
            // console.log( "nick from database is ", nickname );
            resolve( nickname );
        } )
    } );
}
//below is the response
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
test response is  "{\"nickname\":\"caro\"}"
```

Comment: share your jquery code

Comment: @ManojPilania added, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the response is being cached because it is a `GET` request. Try telling jQuery to disable the cache:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "get",
    url: "/getNickname",
    cache: false,          // <--- here
    data: {
        //index: i //my solution
    },
    beforeSend: function ( request ) {

    },
    success: function ( res ) {
        console.log( "test response is ", JSON.stringify( res ) );
    },
    error: function ( err ) {
        reject( err );
    }
} );
```

Comment: @hunewhuan Just like your attempt, jQuery prevents caching by adding an extra parameter to the request, but the value it uses is a unique timestamp.  This is preferable to using numbers 0 - 9 because even those are not unique if you went through the loop twice.

Comment: so the cache is caused by the browser not the jQuery?
 ["Cache-Control", "no-cache"] I searched for this header, and as it says "no-cache" will be ignored by ie,[ie](http://windowsitpro.com/networking/caching-ie),but this is very old,if the latest version of ie can prevent caching XMLHttpRequest by setting 'no-cache' header?

Comment: @hunewhuan Yes, the caching is done by the browser and all jQuery can do is try to prevent the caching from happening. `Cache-Control` is a _response_ header, which means a _server_ can prevent caching by returning this header. It will not do anything useful if you include it in a request. But if you have control over the web application serving the `/getNickname` endpoint, you could try modifying it to return this header.

Comment: oh yeah,now I'm clear!I will try this header in my api,thank you very much!